# Mandrill SMTP timeout

Tags: php, email, symfony, mandrill

I'm using mandrill to send emails from a Symfony2 application.
Everything works on my production and staging servers, both on Amazon, but on my local machine it gives a timeout.

> ERROR - Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection to
>   smtp.mandrillapp.com:587 Timed Out

And other times I get this indicating the same thing, a timeout:

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code
>   250 but got code "421", with message "421 4.4.2 ip-10-107-137-250
>   Error: timeout exceeded

It was working until a few weeks ago, and I thought is was my ISP provider, but now I'm o a different ISP and it's still not working.

I'm using a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 on it, and it works to telnet into mandrill using the below command.

```
telnet smtp.mandrillapp.com 587
Trying 54.73.192.209...
Connected to smtp.eu-west-1.mandrillapp.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP
```

Just the emails from my app are not being sent.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We've started seeing timeouts also. Not all email, but once in a while. We where attributing this to ISP issues also - but we're seeing it across multiple deployments.

Comment: On my machine every request is timeout. If you see intermittent timeouts than you can check their status page http://status.mandrillapp.com/

Comment: We have much more frequent timeouts (daily) than their status page indicates, but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Do you have outgoing firewall software (like Little Snitch for example)?

Comment: No, no firewall configured. And it worked a few weeks ago, and I haven't changed anything on my VM, just reinstalled Ubuntu on my local machine, may there be some default configs on Ubuntu which is preventing the VM to  send emails?

Comment: But if I had any firewall it wouldn't be possible to do the telnet...no?

Comment: I mention little snitch because it can block outgoing connections based on application - so php could be blocked while telnet is ok.

Comment: I've heard that Amazon's default MTU is sometimes interfering with Mandrill connections, and that changing it to 1500 can help. Check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=625256 for related info (not specific to Mandrill).

Answer (score 0):

Recently started seeing timeouts as well. Figured it was the proper time to implement a redundancy check (which should have been done in the first place). So I now try to send the email 3 times, reconnecting between each try. I understand it doesn't fix the timeout issue, but it could prevent other failures/network issues.